# Angular 2 teradata covalent: how to reduse material 2 toolbar height

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

**how to reduce toolbar size in angular material 2??**

I am using Teradata covalent for angular 2 UI.Teradata covalent itself using angular2.

Angular Material 2 toolbar size is too big for me.

So I want to decrease the size of the toolbar. I have tried to look in CSS in my dev console but I didn't find any padding option. I found height property and I try to reduce that height but didn't work for me.

if you want to look at the demo here https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/material-components

scroll down to **Toolbar**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mat-toolbar class of md-toolbar component has a min-height:64px;
You should overwrite it by giving style to md-toolbar like `min-height:30px !important`

Comment: i have already did it, i just forgot to share here. but thank you for giving me answer.